# Unity 3D: Changing sprite animation using UI button

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm following this tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EJOYWBcrzQ) about changing sprite animation in code, and I was wondering if I could change this to changing sprite animation using UI button. does anyone knows how to do this. Thank you!

**EDIT:**
The script that I reposed kind of works thanks to your help, it changes the sprite image from image one to image two but what I'm basically trying to achieve is that each time that I click the UI button the sprite image will change from sprite image one (UI button click)>  sprite image two (UI button click)>  sprite image three (UI button click)>   then repeat the process instead of the sprite image automatically changing itself.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are wanting to do with `Imagethree` so I can't really say. I also edited my answer. When do you want it changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons have an OnClick event  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

You just create a method that gets called when the button is clicked, in your case the changing sprite code. Seen as you are using a timer though you will need to use something like a bool because `onClick()` only gets called once when clicked, not every frame.

Look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ZNuM6K27E

```
bool b_RunSpriteAnim;

public void onClick(){
      b_RunSpriteAnim = true;
}

void Update(){
     if (b_RunSpriteAnim)
         //your anim sprite stuff
}
```

Then once the sprite anim has finished, just toggle `b_RunSpriteAnim` to `false` and reset the timer.

**Edited:**
You don't need a boolean. I only thought you wanted it because you were using a timer (as based on the Youtube link). If you just want to change the sprite immediately then you do not need it. As for `Imagethree` not working, it's because you have never included it in your code. It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve with `Imagethree`, if you included this in `onClick` as well it would just overwrite the image two that was just set, so I am not sure what you are looking to achieve.

```
public void onClick(){
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Imagetwo;
}
```

**Second Edit:**

```
public Sprite[] Images;
//Index starts at one because we are setting the first sprite in Start() method
private int _Index = 1;

void Start(){
    //Set the image to the first one
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[0];
}

public void onClick(){
    //Reset back to 0 so it can loop again if the last sprite has been shown
    if (_Index >= Images.Length)
        _Index = 0;

    //Set the image to array at element index, then increment
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[_Index++];
}
```

Comment: @JesscaStone 9:40 in that turoial, tells you how to bind this onClick method to to the button.

Comment: Um, I tried to reply to you but I didn't have enough characters left so I left my question above in "add an answer", please read it, thank you

Comment: Um, I've edit my question, it would be nice it you can take a look at it. That would be very much appreciated if you took a look at it. Thank you

Comment: @JesscaStone updated. Set the `Images` array in the inspector. This should go from second -> third on button click and then first -> second -> third and loop.

Comment: Thank you, it work. I really appreciate it,  thanks a lot, it really helped.

Comment: Hi, sorry about this but about your script (above) I was wondering if you can help me with something. You see I can't scale the image manually so when I click maximize on play the image stay the same size instead of re-scalling itself and fitting the anchor points. Thank you

Comment: @JesscaStone Make a new post for that. I don't do Unity anymore so I don't really know.